# Why SQLBRITE and why we use it instead of SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlbrite

I am new to android to SQL Brite. i need to learn about SQLBrite how to use and why to use it.I searched in google but there is not much explanation about it only some GitHub codes which is very difficult to understand.

anyone please explain about SQLBrite?

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight wrapper around SQLiteOpenHelper and ContentResolver which introduces reactive stream semantics to queries.

Instead of single executions, you can subscribe to queries using [RxJava observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/):

No attempt is made to hide SQL, Cursor, or the semantics of SQLiteOpenHelper (Android’s SQLite wrapper). Instead, those three concepts are given a superpower: data change notifications.

Whenever data in a table is updated from insert, update, or delete operations (whether in a transaction or as a one-off), subscribers to that data are updated.

When multiple queries are constantly refreshed with data, the UI updates in real-time instead of staying as a simple, static page.

For more reference  : https://corner.squareup.com/2015/02/sqlbrite-reactive-sqlite-for-android.html